# Clearing the data of a Table after a minute in JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have this game in which if I click "Start" button the coins start to appear on the different cells for 1 second and so on the game continues. what I want is that after 1 minute the table should be empty again but this is not happening in my case, the coins continuously coming one after another what should I write so that after a minute table will be empty again.
I can only use JavaScript no jQuery.
HTML:

```js
var img = '<img src="coin.png" alt="coin.png" class="coin_img">';
var count = 0;
function tableCreate(){
    var body = document.body;
    var tbl  = document.createElement('table');
    tbl.style.width  = '730px';
    tbl.style.height = '650px';
    tbl.style.border = '4px solid grey';
 tbl.style.display = 'inline-block';
    for(var i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        var tr = tbl.insertRow();
        for(var j = 0; j < 8; j++){
   var td = tr.insertCell();
            td.style.border = '1px solid black';
   td.style.width = '85px';
   td.style.height = '75px';
   td.id = 'r' + i + 'c' + j;
        }
    }
    body.appendChild(tbl); 
 var alltd = document.getElementsByTagName("td");

 var updateScore = function() {
  var id = this.id;
  var c = document.getElementById(id).childNodes.length;
  if (c) {
    count = count+1;
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "";
  }
 };
 for (var i = 0; i < alltd.length; i++) {
  alltd[i].addEventListener('click', updateScore, false);
 }
}
function initGame() {
 onTimer(); // start overall-timer
 setInterval(function(){ // call createCoins on 600 ms interval
  createCoins()
 }, 1000);
}
function createCoins() {
 // Clear all coins
 var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
 for (i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById(tds[i].id).innerHTML = "";
 }
 // generate new coins
 var cell=[];
 //var count=0;
 var no_of_coins = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 4);
 for (i=0; i<no_of_coins; i++) {
  var row = Math.floor((Math.random() * 8) + 0);
  var col = Math.floor((Math.random() * 8) + 0);
  var cells = 'r' + row + 'c' + col;
  cell.push(cells);
 }
 for (i=0; i< cell.length; i++) {
  var id = cell[i];
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = img;
 }
}
function onTimer() {
    var seconds = 60;
 if (seconds = 60)
 {
    function tick() {
        var counter = document.getElementById("counter");
        seconds--;
        counter.innerHTML = "<h1>Time Left:-"+"0:" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + String(seconds)+"</h1>";
        if( seconds > 0 ) {
            setTimeout(tick, 1000);
        } else {
            alert("Game over");
   showScore();
        }
    }
    tick();
 }
 else
 {
  document.getElementsByTagName("td").innerHTML = '';
 }
}
function showScore()
{ 
 if(count<=15)
 {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="<h2>Score:-"+count+"(You are Fail)</h2>";
 }
 else if(count>15 && count<=30)
 {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="<h2>Score:-"+count+"(You are Pass)</h2>";
 } 
 else if(count>30 && count<=45)
 {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="<h2>Score:-"+count+"(You are Great)</h2>";
 }
 else
 {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="<h2>Score:-"+count+"(Excellent Score)</h2>";
 } 
}
function onRestart()
{ 
 location.reload();
}
```

```css
.button_class
{
 float: left;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 400px;
}
.btn
{
 width: 140px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
 background-color: 
}
.coin_img
{
 width: 100%;
 height: 70px;
}
.counter_div
{
 margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body onload="tableCreate()">
  <div class="button_class">
   <button type="button" name="start_button" class="start_button btn" id="st_button" onclick="initGame()">Start</button>
   <button type="button" name="restart_button"  class="restart_button btn" id="rs_button" onclick="onRestart()">Restart</button>
   <div class="counter_div" id="counter"><h1>Total Time:-1:00</h1></div>
   <div id="result"></div>
  </div>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to clear the interval to you have set to make coins appear when you show `game over` from onTimer function. Also you need to initialize seconds outside onTime() otherwise it will always be 60 each time you call it and `if (seconds = 60)` will always be true because you are assigning 60 to seconds here, use `if (seconds === 60)` instead.

```js
var img = '<img src="coin.png" alt="coin.png" class="coin_img">';
var count = 0, coinInterval;
var seconds;
function tableCreate(){
    var body = document.body;
    var tbl  = document.createElement('table');
    tbl.style.width  = '730px';
    tbl.style.height = '650px';
    tbl.style.border = '4px solid grey';
 tbl.style.display = 'inline-block';
    for(var i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        var tr = tbl.insertRow();
        for(var j = 0; j < 8; j++){
   var td = tr.insertCell();
            td.style.border = '1px solid black';
   td.style.width = '85px';
   td.style.height = '75px';
   td.id = 'r' + i + 'c' + j;
        }
    }
    body.appendChild(tbl); 
 var alltd = document.getElementsByTagName("td");

 var updateScore = function() {
  var id = this.id;
  var c = document.getElementById(id).childNodes.length;
  if (c) {
    count = count+1;
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "";
  }
 };
 for (var i = 0; i < alltd.length; i++) {
  alltd[i].addEventListener('click', updateScore, false);
 }
}
function initGame() {
    seconds = 60;
 onTimer(); // start overall-timer
 coinInterval = setInterval(function(){ // call createCoins on 600 ms interval
  createCoins()
 }, 1000);
}
function createCoins() {
 // Clear all coins
 var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
 for (i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById(tds[i].id).innerHTML = "";
 }
 // generate new coins
 var cell=[];
 //var count=0;
 var no_of_coins = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 4);
 for (i=0; i<no_of_coins; i++) {
  var row = Math.floor((Math.random() * 8) + 0);
  var col = Math.floor((Math.random() * 8) + 0);
  var cells = 'r' + row + 'c' + col;
  cell.push(cells);
 }
 for (i=0; i< cell.length; i++) {
  var id = cell[i];
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = img;
 }
}
function onTimer() {
 if (seconds === 60)
 {
    function tick() {
        var counter = document.getElementById("counter");
        seconds--;
        counter.innerHTML = "<h1>Time Left:-"+"0:" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + String(seconds)+"</h1>";
        if( seconds > 0 ) {
            setTimeout(tick, 1000);
        } else {
            clearInterval(coinInterval);
            alert("Game over");
   showScore();
        }
    }
    tick();
 }
 else
 {
  document.getElementsByTagName("td").innerHTML = '';
 }
}
function showScore()
{ 
 if(count<=15)
 {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="<h2>Score:-"+count+"(You are Fail)</h2>";
 }
 else if(count>15 && count<=30)
 {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="<h2>Score:-"+count+"(You are Pass)</h2>";
 } 
 else if(count>30 && count<=45)
 {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="<h2>Score:-"+count+"(You are Great)</h2>";
 }
 else
 {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="<h2>Score:-"+count+"(Excellent Score)</h2>";
 } 
}
function onRestart()
{ 
 location.reload();
}
```

```css
.button_class
{
 float: left;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 400px;
}
.btn
{
 width: 140px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
 background-color: 
}
.coin_img
{
 width: 100%;
 height: 70px;
}
.counter_div
{
 margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body onload="tableCreate()">
  <div class="button_class">
   <button type="button" name="start_button" class="start_button btn" id="st_button" onclick="initGame()">Start</button>
   <button type="button" name="restart_button"  class="restart_button btn" id="rs_button" onclick="onRestart()">Restart</button>
   <div class="counter_div" id="counter"><h1>Total Time:-1:00</h1></div>
   <div id="result"></div>
  </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: how to empty the table i write document.getElementsByTagName("td").innerHTML = ''; after showScore() but it didn't work

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("td")` will return a list of elements, you will have to set innerHTML of each element = "" inside a loop.

Comment: function onTimer() {
 seconds === 60;
    function tick() {
        var counter = document.getElementById("counter");
        seconds--;
        counter.innerHTML = "<h1>Time Left:-"+"0:" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + String(seconds)+"</h1>";
        if( seconds > 0 ) {
            setTimeout(tick, 1000);
        } else {
            clearInterval(coinInterval);
            alert("Game over");
   showScore();
   document.getElementsByTagName("td").innerHTML = "";
        }
    }
    tick();
}

Comment: what does this loop do?

Comment: Someting related to time

Comment: it has nothing to do with resetting  document.getElementsByTagName("td") cells? where are you emptying the table?

Comment: Where i should empty the table?I think after the time(1 minute) is over.

Comment: yes that would be correct, just after show you game over

Comment: So after alert?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151038/discussion-between-dij-and-naveen-dharni).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by stop the interval.

```
var coinsInterval = setInterval(createCoin, 1000);
//run when you want to stop
clearInterval(coinsInterval);

//or if you really need to time 1 min to stop, use setTimeOut
setTimeOut(function() {
    clearInterval(coinsInterval);
},60000);
```

The function will only stop the interval. You still have to do the clean up yourself (delete the current coin)

Answer (score 0):

Also, put this code below showScore() function so all td element tag will be blank

```
var length = document.querySelectorAll('td').length;
for(i = 0; i< length;i++) {
   document.getElementsByTagName('td')[i].innerHTML = '';
 }
```